# Access to php array inner

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array print like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["systems"]=>
  array(5) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1111"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2222"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "3333"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "4444"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "5555"
  }
  ["test"]=>
  string(2) "on"
}
```

Now , i want to access to every every inner value with using foreach or any code that will work with that code.

I mean for example, I want to echo Out something like this :

```
System "1" has "1111" value.
System "2" has "2222" value.
System "3" has "3333" value.
System "4" has "4444" value.
System "5" has "5555" value.
```

How can i have that output code ?

Comment: @Mark I have really tried using foreach loop but i got error every every time.

Comment: @user3394468 It would be better to share your code, and your error message so we can help you troubleshoot the issue you are having, and help you understand what you are doing wrong. This is very much preferred to 'do the work for me' kinds of questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print the keys of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507381/print-the-keys-of-an-array)

Comment: Consider adding an update, because you currently have many answers and it is still not clear what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$array = array(
    'systems' => array(
        1 => 1111,
        2 => 2222,
        3 => 3333,
        4 => 4444,
        5 => 5555
    ),
    'test' => 'on'
);

foreach ($array['systems'] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'System "' . $key . '" has "' . $value . '" value.'."<br />\n";
}
```

if your name of your variable is `$array`.

Comment: Tnx , But two errors i have : 1-Warning:  Illegal string offset 'systems' 2- Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: check my edited post. i think, your array has no `systems` key.

Comment: I have this error again! do you know what the problem is ?

Comment: You haev no `systems` key in your array. `var_dump();` your array.

Answer (score 2):

Such as the following.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray){
    foreach ($subarray as $name => $value){
        echo '<p>'.$key.' "'.$name.'" has "'.$value.'" value.</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($array['systems'] as $key1 => $value1) {
         echo "SYSTEM".$key1."has".$value1."value";
         echo "<br>";

     }
```

Comment: why do you looping through the rest of the array?

Comment: yes, we can do it by looping first one only.