# How to give name to array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have data like:

```
array:3 [▼
  "jne" => "Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)"
  "pos" => "POS Indonesia (POS)"
  "tiki" => "Citra Van Titipan Kilat (TIKI)"
]
```

I only need `jne, pos, tiki` part of this array but i can't get them. I tried to map them like:

```
$couriers = collect($results)->map(function ($item) {
  return ['title' => $item];
})->toArray();
```

it returns:

```
array:3 [▼
  "jne" => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)"
  ]
  "pos" => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "POS Indonesia (POS)"
  ]
  "tiki" => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "Citra Van Titipan Kilat (TIKI)"
  ]
]
```

**How can I get those data 3 titles in 1 array so I can loop it in my view?**

## Code

```
$rajaongkir = new Raja\Domestic($key);
$results = $rajaongkir->courier('all');

$couriers = collect($results)->map(function ($item) {
  return ['title' => $item];
})->toArray();

dd($couriers);
```

Comment: use array_keys() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print the keys of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507381/print-the-keys-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all keys of an array.

```
$arr = [
  'jne'  => 'Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)',
  'pos'  => 'POS Indonesia (POS)',
  'tiki' => 'Citra Van Titipan Kilat (TIKI)',
];

$keys = array_keys($arr);
print_r($keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a snippet like this:

```
$results = [
  "jne" => [
    "title" => "Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)"
  ],
  "pos" => [
    "title" => "POS Indonesia (POS)"
  ],
  "tiki" => [
    "title" => "Citra Van Titipan Kilat (TIKI)"
  ],
];

$couriers = array_map(function($title) {
    return ['title' => $title];
}, array_keys($results));
```